# I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 2

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to implement AdMob in my application, I'm getting the below error

### My Error is :

```
 I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
 I/Ads: Ad failed to load: 2
```

### Java code :

```
MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
AdView adView=(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adv_id);

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(
AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

### XML

```
ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```